# Applying class method to queryset in Django

Tags: django

I am new to advanced concepts of Django, and I find myself a bit confused about the application of concepts such as custom methods.

Basically, my goal is best descriped by this short example. 
I have two classes, namely vendor and order. Each order has a vendor. The models look like this:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    vendor_agreement = models.ForeignKey(VendorAgreement, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    @property
    def get_vendor_agreement(self):
       ....
       return result
```

As you see, I have all the business logic between an `order` and `vendor_agreement` encapsulated in the `get_vendor_agreement` method.

**The question** Is there any elegant way to get the list of distinct `vendor_agreements` that correspond to `order` queryset ? I mean, something like `Order.objects.filter(...).vendor_agreement()`, which would return a list of distinct vendor agreements.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From official [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager):

```
from django.db import models

class Reporter(models.Model):
    # ...
    pass

class Article(models.Model):
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In the above example, the methods below will be available on the manager reporter.article_set.

Also, you can use [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) method which will join your data in one query.

In your case code should look like:

```
order_list = Order.objects.filter(...).prefetch_related('vendor_agreement')
for order in order_list:
    print order
    for vendor_agreement in order.vendor_agreement_set.all():
        print vendor_agreement
```

Code from my example will hit database only once.

Comment: prefetch_related, not select_related... But anyway - read this document: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/